# How do you control resolution and/or scaling of icons in RDP connections in Windows 8.1?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1

How do you control resolution and/or scaling of icons in RDP connections in Windows 8.1?, when using either ...

- the new "Remote Desktop" store app
- the old desktop "Remote Desktop Connection"

I've got a laptop and Surface Pro 3, both Windows 8.1, connecting to a desktop PC, again Windows 8.1

The Surface is fine, if high resolution, but the laptop connection has got very large icons on the desktop

Is there some way to control this? ... not the size text for the icons, which can be changed in `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalisation\Display`

EDIT: added point concerns store or desktop connection

Comment: When you connect, you can set the resolution in the RDP options... Click `show options` and then choose `Display` tab.

Comment: @Dave Are you referring to the old desktop "Remote Desktop Connection" ... I was trying the new "Remote Desktop" store application, but it's "Edit" option doesn't seem to have a resolution choice? Even with the old RDC, I still get enormous desktop icons

Comment: I wonder if you can check the text size to make sure it's not only 125% or similar

Comment: @Dave Crossing postings ... icon text set to 10 point, can't see a 125%?

Answer (score 0):

Jist: DPI redirection works, but only on new sessions. On existing sessions, the DPI of the existing session is used.

Please see this answer that I gave some time ago: [Remote Desktop into Windows 8.1 PC with high DPI scaling](https://superuser.com/questions/830234/remote-desktop-into-windows-8-1-pc-with-high-dpi-scaling/830283#830283)

Comment: On the plus side, Win 10 seems to work a bit better (DWM and explorer seem to scale some parts of the UI now).