# windows 10: multiple desktops: Can I make display settings specific per desktop?

Tags: windows-10

In order to get remote desktop client useful ([see the battle here](https://superuser.com/q/1030041/15466)), I thought to use a dedicated desktop, set to scale everything larger.

But it appears the display setting is global, across all desktops.

Is it possible to lock display settings to a virtual desktop? (Or get close?)

**Why I need this**: On my new surface 4, some applications (remote desktop client, and an html editor I depend on) do not work properly at high dpi. I don't want to mess with the surface overall (which is great), but I need a "workspace" that has different display settings where I can run these applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try kludging the Settings.

1. Click on the Windows icon on the Task Bar at bottom left of screen and click on Settings.
2. Click icon labeled System if you need to setup multiple monitors
3. Settings | Personalization | BackGround section has,  Picture and Slideshow
4. I'm assuming 2 monitors are in use. For monitor 1: Set a Picture as the background. For monitor 2: create a Folder with just 1 image copied into it and set monitor 2 to use Slideshow.

Comment: OP enhanced to describe the background for the need... (and why your proposal appears not applicable)  Thanks!