# How to exactly use mRemoteNG to scale/zoom in on RDP?

Tags: remote-desktop

I creating new question for clarification since I can't comment on existing questions due to 50 reps required. The following two questions mention **mRemoteNG** automatically scales/zoom RDP connections. But I have trouble implementing this solution.

[Remote Desktop: Zoom AND full screen -- how? (Win10 remote, Win7, 2008 & 2003 hosts)](https://superuser.com/questions/1030041/remote-desktop-zoom-and-full-screen-how-win10-remote-win7-2008-2003-ho/1031862#1031862)

[Can I scale (stretch) a Remote Desktop session locally?](https://superuser.com/questions/1268206/can-i-scale-stretch-a-remote-desktop-session-locally)

1. I have set Resolution to 1280x1024 and hoping it will scale to fill the blank gray area or full screen.
2. I have tried the Smart Sizing on and off, plus the Fullscreen mode without luck
3. I would prefer to get mRemoteNG working. I have tried various other applicable solutions from the above two answers without much success.
4. What is exact setting needed to trigger mRemoteNG to upscale the RDP session?

[Screen Shot of mRemoteNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHaMT.png)

Answer (score 3):

There's a GitHub issue about this, and [a comment in that thread](https://github.com/mRemoteNG/mRemoteNG/issues/1427#issuecomment-776001933) has a workaround for the issue:

> A workaround for this issue on Windows 10: Find mRemoteNG.exe file, open "Properties" -> "Compatibility" -> "Change high DPI settings" -> "High DPI scaling override", turn on "Override high DPI scaling behavior" option and set "Scaling performed by:" to "System" or "System (Enhanced)", not "Application".